# How to remove publish code update in expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I configured the module as a `stand-alone app` to use it. So when I'm building the Android APK, I'm running the "`expo publicish,`" and I'm making the APK in the Android studio.

By the way, I found that if I changed the **Expo source** , it would be **automatically updated**.

How do I prevent this kind of automatic update?

> expo-cli version: expo-cli 2.18.5
>
> "expo": "^30.0.0",

my App.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "test",
    "description": "This project is really great.",
    "slug": "test",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "30.0.0",
    "packagerOpts": {
      "config": "./rn-cli.config.js"
    },
    "platforms": ["android"],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",

    "android": {
      "package": "com.jackson.myapp",
      "publishBundlePath": "android/app/src/main/assets/shell-app.bundle",
      "publishManifestPath": "android/app/src/main/assets/shell-app-manifest.json",
      "splash": {
        "backgroundColor": "#000000"
      }
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "usesIcloudStorage": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.jackson.myapps",
      "publishBundlePath": "ios/mvw/Supporting/shell-app.bundle",
      "publishManifestPath": "ios/mvw/Supporting/shell-app-manifest.json"
    },
    "isDetached": true,
    "detach": {
      "iosExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/ios-v2.8.4-sdk30.0.0-3de13133-1adc-4ba1-85691e570b4.tar.gz",
      "androidExpoViewUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/exp-exponent-view-code/android-v2.8.1-sdk30.0.0-0fde103b-be3d-43f9-bc48-30336971.tar.gz"
    },
    "scheme": "exp6c94a01048724a76bc92dca0c"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android, you will need to change the default settings.

you take a look at the ExpoKit note under [this section](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/workflow/configuration/#updates)

you guessing that for

> AppConstants.java

, you need to set this line:

```
public static boolean ARE_REMOTE_UPDATES_ENABLED = false;
```

you have to run `expo publish` at least once before you make the APK.